# For changing Bitbucket IPs (incoming/outgoing) is there a URL I can hit to discover changes?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

This document is helpful:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html

but only really readable by a human. I want to update our firewalls automatically, or at least alert ourselves of changes to the Bitbucket IPs. Is there some API route I can hit for Bitbucket to determine changes to their IPs?

Answer (score 0):

https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/ is an up-to-date JSON list of all Atlassian-associated IPs.